# Symfony 2.8 & HWIOAuthBundle: You have requested a synthetic service ("request"). The DIC does not know how to construct this service

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, hwioauthbundle

I use HWIOAuthBundle for facebook login and I get this error after updating from 2.8.9 to 2.8.10:

```
You have requested a synthetic service ("request"). The DIC does not know how to construct this service.
```

I have read https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19840 and seems some people overcome the issue, but mine is still remaining.

Here is the configuration that might cause the error.

config.yml:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: secured_area
    http_client:
        verify_peer:    false
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:           facebook
            client_id:      "%facebook_client_id%"
            client_secret:  "%facebook_client_secret%"
            scope:          email
            infos_url:      https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name
            options:
                display: popup
                auth_type: rerequest
```

security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    oauth:
        resource_owners:
                facebook: /sign-in/check-facebook
            login_path:     /sign-in
            use_forward:    false
            failure_path:   /sign-in
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: my_custom_user_provider
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony 2.8.11 fixed the problem. Error is not appearing after update from 2.8.10 to 2.8.11.

Comment: Related issue on Github: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19840